# Can't solve index.js?

Tags: asp.net, angular

I created a common angular + asp.net app and hasn't changed anything. But when I try to run dotnet I get this message

I have the latest version of Angular, DotNet, Npm, Node

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\Users\1\Desktop\C#\ASP NET\vsCodeProject\asp_net_app\ClientApp\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\client\index.js?protocol=auto%3A&username=&password=&hostname=0.0.0.0&port=0&pathname=%2Fng-cli-ws&logging=info&overlay=%7B%22errors%22%3Atrue%2C%22warnings%22%3Afalse%7D&reconnect=10&hot=false&live-reload=true' in 'C:\Users\1\Desktop\C#\ASP NET\vsCodeProject\asp_net_app\ClientApp'

Answer (score 0):

To solve that problem you can try below :

```
npm install
npm cache clean --force
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

If it is not work please ensure that your webpack-dev-server version.
Lastly you can try to delete the ***node_modules*** and ***dist*** folders and npm install again.

Comment: It didn't help at all :(